# better way for responsive css background image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i need to responsive css background image. Which of these are better? Or any better way?

1: add `img tag`

HTML:

```
<body>
    <img src="largeimage.jpg">
    <img class="smallscreen" src="smallimage.jpg>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
img.smallscreen { display: none; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    img { 
        display: none; 
    }
    img.smallscreen { 
        display: inline; 
    }
}
```

2: add css image background into div tag

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="image"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#image { 
    background-image: url(largeimage.jpg); 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    #image { 
        background-image: url(smallimage.jpg); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are loading two images there, so dont you think it is better just to make one request for the image? so in this case if the image it will be a the background of the entire page you could use something like `cover` fx:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

or if does really need to be inside a div as you have it it could go something like this:

```
img.bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
  }
}
```

[Source](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

***Browser Support:***

**Firefox (Gecko)**
Mozilla Firefox 4.0+ (Gecko 2.0+) offers full support for the background-size property.
Prior to version 4.0, `-moz-background-size` was supported from Firefox 3.6 (Gecko 1.9.2), however this is no longer support from 4.0 onward.

**Internet Explorer**
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0+ offers full support for the background-size property.
Prior to version 9.0, Internet Explorer offered no support for background-size.

**Opera**
Opera 10.0+ offers full support for the background-size property.
Prior to version 10.0, `-o-background-size` was supported in Opera 9.5, however there were some descrepancies between Opera’s implementation and the CSS3 specification.

**Safari / Chrome (Webkit)**
Safari 4.1+ (webkit 532) and Chrome 3.0+ both offer full support for the background-size property.

Comment: [There aren't](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) `-moz-` `-ms-` and `-o-` vendor prefixes for background-size property

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the second one. Do it all in the CSS. Although you could just set the background on the body, without the div, unless there is a reason not to. You would just replace #image with body. This is fine and there is not a better way than you already have.